# Cakephp $this->redirect function is not working

Tags: php, cakephp, header

I have just migrated my site from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.2 and Cakephp `$this->redirect()` function has stopped working.

I tried many things but only JavaScript redirect  works.

--Upgraded server PHP from 5.2 to 5.3 (not worked)

I have faced this(PHP header) issue many times before.
Please suggest a way to solve this.

Comment: some further infos that could be helpful would be the version of Cake and also a snippet of the non working code

Comment: Do you have any error messages ? Is your Cakephp writing errors in log file ?

Comment: What's the error you're getting ? Post the code you're using. We need more details since we're not using magical crystal balls here.

Comment: Did you change 5.3->5.2 or the other way around? Your post is confusing about it.

Comment: And if it's a "headers already sent" issue, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php), this question has been asked many times already.

Comment: no I changes 5.2->5.3

Answer (score 2):

In your controller where you want to redirect,check is there any blank space exists.I modified my controller and it was working fine for me.

Comment: `redirect` is declared in `Controller`, so you cannot use it in the model

Comment: yea, it is defined in controller. And i have many controllers. I have checked them for the spaces but it is not working.